# How to count/indicate if a prior within group interaction exists?

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I looked through a lot of count and pair related questions but couldn't find a solution to this problem.

My data has thousands of groups over time that have different compositions of agents in them. Each group has one or more leaders indicated by the dummy. Over time many agents tend to be repeat leaders. I'm trying to find a way to make a dummy that indicates if a prior interaction exists between the leader and other agents. Ideally I would like to count interactions cumulatively, but frankly I can't even think of a way it could be done which wouldn't get out of hand due to the large number of agents, groups and rows in the sample.

To illustrate the problem take group 1672. I'd like to somehow count or take note of all the relationships between the leader (agent_id 6031) and the other members in a way that when later in the sample these relationships repeat, they would be counted in a new column. I'll make a hypothetical example below

```
structure(list(year = c(1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 
1987L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 
1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 
1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L
), group_id = c(1672L, 1672L, 1672L, 1672L, 1672L, 1672L, 1672L, 
5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 
5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 
5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 5838L, 6143L, 6143L, 7044L, 7044L, 7044L, 
7044L, 7044L, 7044L, 7044L, 7044L, 7044L, 7044L, 7044L), agent_id = c(7836L, 
7878L, 5855L, 8864L, 8857L, 7910L, 6031L, 5846L, 7878L, 5891L, 
7838L, 7828L, 8926L, 5919L, 5925L, 5933L, 8857L, 5978L, 8834L, 
7888L, 8903L, 6014L, 8859L, 6059L, 7845L, 2446L, 6127L, 8902L, 
5893L, 8995L, 8836L, 7836L, 7878L, 6309L, 7828L, 6138L, 5952L, 
7844L, 7845L, 6084L, 7910L, 6532L), leader_dummy = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


# A tibble: 20 x 4
    year group_id agent_id leader_dummy
   <int>    <int>    <int>        <dbl>
 1  1987     1672     7836            0
 2  1987     1672     7878            0
 3  1987     1672     5855            0
 4  1987     1672     8864            0
 5  1987     1672     8857            0
 6  1987     1672     7910            0
 7  1987     1672     6031            1
 8  1989     5838     5846            0
 9  1989     5838     7878            0
10  1989     5838     5891            0
11  1989     5838     7838            0
12  1989     5838     7828            0
13  1989     5838     8926            0
14  1989     5838     5919            0
15  1989     5838     5925            0
16  1989     5838     5933            0
17  1989     5838     8857            0
18  1989     5838     5978            0
19  1989     5838     8834            0
20  1989     5838     7888            0
```

Example of the desired outcome (just edited the above date to show what I'm going for):

```
year group_id agent_id leader_dummy   prior_interactions
1987     1672     7836            0   0
1987     1672     7878            0   0 
1987     1672     5855            0   0
1987     1672     8864            0   0
1987     1672     8857            0   0
1987     1672     7910            0   0
1987     1672     6031            1   0     
 .
 . 
 .
1990     2549     5846            0   0
1990     2549     7878            1   0 
1990     2549     5891            0   0
1990     2549     6031            0   1   #was in the same group (1672) with leader  
1990     2549     7828            0   0
1990     2549     8926            0   0
1990     2549     5855            0   0
 .
 .
 .
1991     8785     7878            0   1   #was in the same group (1672) with leader
1991     8785     1065            0   0
1991     8785     7910            0   1   #was in the same group (1672) with leader
1991     8785     2084            0   0
1991     8785     6031            1   0
 . 
 .
 .
1993     9526     8926            1   0
1993     9526     7878            0   1   #was in the same group (2549) with leader
1993     9526     2888            0   0
1993     9526     1003            0   0
 .
 .
 .
1994     10260    7878            1   0
1994     10260    1065            0   1   #was in the same group (8785) with leader
1994     10260    8926            0   1   #was in the same group (9526) with leader
1994     10260    6031            0   1   #was in the same group (1672, 2549, 8785)  with leader   
1994     10260    1533            1   0
 .
 .
 .
1995     11044    7860            0   0
1995     11044    1533            1   0
1995     11044    7828            0   0
1995     11044    6138            0   0
1995     11044    1065            0   1   #was in the same group (10260) with leader
1995     11044    7844            0   0
1995     11044    8926            0   1   #was in the same group (10260) with leader
1995     11044    6084            0   0
1995     11044    7878            0   1   #was in the same group (10260) with leader
```

The fact that there can be multiple leaders, leading to an increased number of interactions within a group, further complicates the issue.

**Clarification:**
My example before wasn't very clear in what I was trying to achieve. I hope the modifications above clarify things. If not please let me know and I'll try to continue the example.

But basically there are a lot of repeated interactions between agents in the data and as they form relationships they collaborate more and more. I'm somehow trying to measure that formation of networks. If I could then measure the number of these interactions as they accumulate through time that would be even better, but probably hard to do.

Comment: Maybe you could try to clarify a bit the desired outcome on a simple example to help the community answering your problem :).

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. It's a bit hard to explain :/ I tried improving my example so please let me know if the idea is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 6031 I have given 7878 leader dummy value 1. See if following is your desire output.

```
agent_ID <- df$agent_id[which(df$leader_dummy==1)]
agent_ID_index <- which(df$leader_dummy==1)

vec <- c()
for (k in 1:nrow(df)) {
  print(k)
  if ((df$agent_id[k] %in% agent_ID)&(!(k %in% agent_ID_index))) {
    vec[k] <- 1
  }else{
    vec[k] <- 0
  }
}
df$check <-vec
```

output

```
# A tibble: 42 x 5
    year group_id agent_id leader_dummy check
   <int>    <int>    <int>        <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1987     1672     7836            0     0
 2  1987     1672     7878            1     0
 3  1987     1672     5855            0     0
 4  1987     1672     8864            0     0
 5  1987     1672     8857            0     0
 6  1987     1672     7910            0     0
 7  1987     1672     6031            0     0
 8  1989     5838     5846            0     0
 9  1989     5838     7878            0     1
10  1989     5838     5891            0     0
11  1989     5838     7838            0     0
12  1989     5838     7828            0     0
13  1989     5838     8926            0     0
14  1989     5838     5919            0     0
15  1989     5838     5925            0     0
16  1989     5838     5933            0     0
17  1989     5838     8857            0     0
18  1989     5838     5978            0     0
19  1989     5838     8834            0     0
20  1989     5838     7888            0     0
21  1989     5838     8903            0     0
22  1989     5838     6014            0     0
23  1989     5838     8859            0     0
24  1989     5838     6059            0     0
25  1989     5838     7845            0     0
26  1989     5838     2446            0     0
27  1989     5838     6127            0     0
28  1989     5838     8902            0     0
29  1989     5838     5893            1     0
30  1989     6143     8995            0     0
31  1989     6143     8836            1     0
32  1990     7044     7836            0     0
33  1990     7044     7878            0     1
34  1990     7044     6309            0     0
35  1990     7044     7828            0     0
36  1990     7044     6138            0     0
37  1990     7044     5952            0     0
38  1990     7044     7844            0     0
39  1990     7044     7845            0     0
40  1990     7044     6084            0     0
41  1990     7044     7910            0     0
42  1990     7044     6532            1     0
```

Comment: Not really but thank you for trying. It was in the right direction though (I think). I don't know if the question even makes sense or is worth the effort. The solution would require the agent at every row to be compared only to the agents in the past and see if it had been in a prior group where (1) the leader of the group is the same as the leader of its current group or (2) if it had itself been a leader in a group where the current group leader was a member. Even explaining the idea is a pain so I don't know how solvable this is.